# I need to convert a CSV file to a Json file using python with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, parsing

I need to convert a large CSV file with data(numbers) to a json file. I am using python with the library pandas. Each index has 5 attributes with values.

```
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=[0, 1])

elec = []
elec_pd = []

for x in range(5,645,5):
    elec.append(data.iloc[:,x-5:x].values)
    elec_pd.append(data.iloc[:,x-5:x])

JsonData = data.to_json(orient='split')

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(JsonData, outfile)
```

I tried this but the json file gets too messy

What I expect is a Json format like this:

```
{ 
    { 
       index: 1
             { 
                 At1: 0
                 At2: 0
                 At3: 0
                 At4: 0
                 At5: 0
             }
       index: 2 
             {
                 At1: 0
                 At2: 0
                 At3: 0
                 At4: 0
                 At5: 0
             }
     }
}
```

And so on

[Part of the CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKwj1.png)

Comment: just wondering... are you sure that you actually can't use the csv without converting? csv is more or less handable everywhere in the world of computers... ps. you have not said how you want your json to look like (when it looks nice)...

Comment: @ahed87 Thank you for the comment. I tried to use CSV at the first place but I need to convert it to json somehow. I just updated the question.

Comment: Is the JSON file in the correct format, just 'not pretty'? If so, just download any json prettifyer for your text editor of choice to solve the issue.

Comment: ok, so where did you actually trip on not being able to use the csv? just wondering since to me it still sounds easiest to not convert a csv to json but rather use it directly. also your entered "ok" json is not passing a json validator with std settings at least (there are several that you can use online). just wondering how you in the end actually would process your wanted json.